# Fixed field of automorphism $t\mapsto t+1$ of $k(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm working on the following problem:

> Determine the fixed field of the automorphism $t\mapsto t+1$ of $k(t)$. (Ex 7, section 14.1, *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit & Foote).

Here is my attempt of a solution:

Let be $\sigma$ the automorphism determined by $t\mapsto t+1$ and fixing $k$. An arbitrary element of $\alpha(t)\in k(t)$ has the form $\alpha(t)=\dfrac{p(t)}{q(t)}$ with $p,q\in k\left[ t\right]$. We can take $p,q$ such that $(p,q)=1$ and $q$ monic. If $\alpha$ is a fixed element by $\sigma$, then we have $\alpha(t)=\alpha(t+1)$, so that $\dfrac{p(t)}{q(t)}=\dfrac{p(t+1)}{q(t+1)}$ and finally $p(t)q(t+1)=p(t+1)q(t)$. As $(p,q)=1$, $q(t)$ must divide $q(t+1)$. By the same reason, $q(t)$ must divide $q(t+1)$, and as we took $q$ monic, we conclude that $q(t+1)=q(t)$, ie, $\sigma(q(t))=q(t)$. Now we note that, as $\sigma$ fixes both $\alpha(t)$ and $q(t)$, it must also fix $p(t)$.

Now I'm getting stuck. If the characteristic of the field $k$ is $0$, I can say both $p$ and $q$ have an infinite number of roots (if they're not constant polynomials), so both have to be constant. But if the characteristic is non-zero, I can't conclude in the same way. What can I say about the polynomials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perez  CAn you please tell rigoriously why $\sigma$ $\alpha(t)$  and q(t) implies it will also fix p(t)?

Comment: Perez also why If char of field is 0 , then how to deduce that p and q have infinitely many roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't come to a contradiction when $\operatorname{char}k=p$, you can still conclude quite a bit using the same reasoning.

Suppose that $p(t)$ has a root $\alpha\in\overline{k}$.  Then you've shown that it must have roots $\alpha+1, \alpha+2,\ldots$.  So you can conclude that $p(t)$ is divisible by the product of $(x-\alpha+n)$ for $n=0,1,\ldots p-1$.  Can you compute this product explicitly, and conclude that $p(t)$ must have a very specific form?

Comment: Dear Sir I calculated p(t)=t^p-t=0 using Fermats little thoeorem Is this means Only 0 is required  fixed field?

Answer (score 4):

Also, if $\text{char }K = p$, then the subgroup generated by $\sigma(t) = t+1$ is finite (it has order $p$), and thus we can apply Artin's theorem to conclude that $K(t)/K(t)^{\sigma}$ has degree $p$ (since it is a Galois extension and its Galois group is isomorphic to $\langle\sigma\rangle$). Now it is enough to notice that $K(t^p-t) \subseteq K(t)^{\sigma}$ and $[K(t) : K(t^p-t)] = p$, hence $K(t)^{\sigma} = K(t^p-t)$.